# Migrated from TCL8.4 to 8.5 and Im facing issues with the file sourcing

Tags: tcl

My application runs well on RHEL 5 (TCL 8.4). But in RHEL 7 64bit TCL8.5, the database files are not sourced in correctly.  The application is by default pointing to the last record file in the db.  Hence, im assuming it might be issue with the way 8.5 handles the file sourcing. So i created a file X and wrote the below code. (Please ignore dbname and /path, it works fine)

File X

```
#!/bin/sh
# \
exec tclsh "$0" "$@"
puts [package require Itcl]
namespace import ::itcl::*
puts $itcl::patchLevel
puts $itcl::library
set databases /dbname
set system ($databases,dbpath) /path
source File.class.tcl
source FareFile.class.tcl
puts [Fare.File formtitle]
source Record1File.class.tcl
puts [Fare.File formtitle]
```

I source FareFile in and print the form title(o/p: Fare Viewer) using the formtitle method which is declared in the File.class.tcl.  And then I source Record1File and print the FareFile formtitle (the first one), its printing the form title of Record1File.  The formtitle method is returning the value of the lastest sourced file.  This does not happen in 8.4

File.class.tcl:

```
class File {

    variable fileinfo
    variable recordarray

    variable allads_flag 0
    variable updates_is_lastkey 0

    method formtitle {} {
            variable fileinfo
            return $fileinfo(formtitle)
    }
}
```

FareFile.class.tcl

```
FareFile ::Fare.File

::Fare.File parse_fields {
            tabtitle "Fares"
            formtitle "Fare Viewer"
         }
```

Record1File.class.tcl

```
Record1File ::Record1.File

::Record1.File  parse_fields {
            tabtitle "Record 1"
            formtitle "Record 1 Viewer"
```

output in 8.4 / RHEL 5: (Expected output in 8.5)

```
3.4
3.4.0
/path
Fare Viewer
Fare Viewer
```

output in 8.5 / RHEL 7:

```
3.4
3.4.3
/path
Fare Viewer
Record 1 Viewer
```

If you see the output on both platforms, its different.  Please help

Comment: Welcome! Can you show us what `[Fare.File formtitle]`does, how it is implemented? (I guess, its implementation is in `FareFile.class.tcl`)? Pls. also improve the formatting of your question. For example, make sure that code listings and expected output listings are clearly separated, to avoid confusion. Output printouts should also be formatted distinct from the describing text lines.

Comment: This line should result in a syntax error: `set system ($databases,dbpath) /path` -- too many arguments

Comment: @mrcalvin Thank you and sorry for the question formatting.  I have edited the post.  Please check and suggest.  Thanks :)

Comment: You scripts are still not correct, I am afraid: See glenn's comment, and the Record1File.class.tcl printout misses a closing brace. Aside: I cannot tell how all the File subclasses are meant to be related, guesswork: `FareFile` is a subclass of `File`? `Record1File` is a subclass of `File`?

Comment: The issue is that this _might_ be something subtle in the definition of the `FareFile` class (or one of its superclasses) in how it interacts with things — possibly even a place where the behaviour it was depending on was actually a bug that got fixed somewhere — or it could be some other confounding gross change. The information you've given us lacks (many!) critical details that might let us decide. We can't give good help without more information. For example, the definition of the `parse_fields` method is completely absent…

Comment: @mrcalvin : Yes Both FareFile and Record1 inherit File class. Please ignore the braces and minor definitions. I just posted a chunk of code since its huge.  I added the parse_fields just to show the value of formtitle.

Comment: Donal Fellows, I ll try to put the issue in simple words again.  2 files (FareFile Record1) inherits File class)  I wrote a script to printout the formtitle (This method is declared in File class.  In the script, when i source Farefile and print the value of formtitle, output is "Fare Viewer" and when i source Record1 in and print the FareFile formtitle, output is "Record 1 Viewer".

The formtitle is returning the value of latest sourced file which is an issue.  This was not happening in tcl8.4.  Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: "I just posted a chunk of code since its huge." If that it the case, then you have to reduce it to a mininal example that still shows the misbehaviour, I am afraid. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -1):

(This is only a tentative answer, given all the blanks of the question, but I need the formatting capabilities:)

Try the following pls., by rewriting the body script of method `formtitle` as follows:

```
class File {
    method formtitle {} {
            set v variable
            $v fileinfo
            return $fileinfo(formtitle)
    }
}
```

... and report back by posting a comment.

Comment: Damn. There used to be issues with the resolution mechanism used by Itcl 3.4 (resolvers) in the past. Thought they could have reappeared.